# Pathfinder : about the Riding Dog's "Loyal" quality

Tags: pathfinder-1e, animal-companions

This is a question about a missing detail in PF rules.

According to the [Dog Breeds](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/dog/breeds) rules, Riding Dogs have a special quality called "Loyal" as Animal Companions at 4th level advancement. The problem is, I searched in every site I could find and *I never found a description of it anywhere.*

Then I really want to know what it is about exactly. Every other Medium dog breed seems to have a kind of special quality by default (mentioned and described in their bestiary entries) that they only have at 4th level advancement as Animal Companions.

By the way, a lot of special qualities of other dog breeds are left unexplained as well. I will take any explanation for them as well.

Answer (score 2):

That dog breeds information appears to be third party content from [Phantasia Zoologica Volume 1](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8ocd?Phantasia-Zoologica-Volume-I-Cats-Dogs-Horses), so the definition is likely in there.